# MS Graph API - error message contradicts supplied json request

Tags: http, python-requests, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to use Microsoft Graph API via python requests library to 1. create a sharelink to a folder in Onedrive and 2. change the permissions so that specific users who get the link can access it.

Part 1 works. The response returned gives me the shareLink and encoded shareId. When I use the shareLink (and I obviously have permissions) it takes me to the folder.
Part 2 returns an error. The message attached to the error says:

`'error': {'code': 'invalidRequest', 'message': 'Invite must be called with a list of recipients',`

but...

I am supplying a list of recipients!

````
request = json.dumps({
        "recipients": [{'email':'user@email.com'}],
        "roles": ["read"]
        })

response=requests.post(
        GRAPH_API_ENDPOINT + '/shares/' + share_id + '/permission/grant',
        headers=headers,
        json=request
        )```

The docs for this function are [permission-grant graph api][1]

I assume Invite is being called internally when I post to permission. Why does it think I am not sending recipients? The format I'm supplying is same as the example in the docs.


[1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/permission-grant?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
````

Answer (score 0):

It works if I write json directly:

```
request = {
        "recipients": [{'email':'user@email.com'}],
        "roles": ["read"]
        }
```

credit due: [Microsoft Q & A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1288204/ms-graph-api-add-permissions-driveitem-error-invit)